# PowerShell ForEach loop, Wildcard, problem constraining set-content with multiple subfolders

Tags: powershell, foreach, wildcard

New to PowerShell! Below code works great when there is only 1 subfolder (C:\Desktop\Project\ChapterOne\Section1\Table1.txt, for instance). It takes content of all "Table*.txt" files (like Table1.txt, Table2.txt, Table3.txt) and compiles it into one file: AllTables.txt.

```
Get-ChildItem "$home\Desktop\Project\ChapterOne\*\"
ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path $home\Desktop\Project\ChapterOne\*\ -ItemType file -Name "AllTables.txt" -Force
    $basedir = "$home\Desktop\Project\ChapterOne\*\"
    $outfile = "$home\Desktop\Project\ChapterOne\*\AllTables.txt"
    Get-ChildItem $basedir -Include Table*.txt -Recurse | Get-Content | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

However, when there are multiple subfolders, say when ChapterOne has 2 subfolders Section1 and Section2, each with a few Table*.txt files in them, the code takes all tables of BOTH Section1 and Section2 and adds them to the AllTables.txt files in each subfolder. I want just the Table*.txt files of Section1 in the AllTables.txt file of Section1, and just the Table*.txt files of Section2 in its AllTables.txt file.

Is the problem the wildcards? How can I confine the operation to every subfolder even when I won't know the subfolder names or how many there are?

I am open to a completely new way of achieving this result. I always learn a lot in this forum.

Comment: 0th, you are not sending anything into your `ForEach` cmdlet. ///// perhaps you could ... 1st, get the list of subdirs. 2nd, add a `foreach` loop that iterates thru the subdirs. 3rd, do your stuff for that subdir. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you. Updated post above--still having same issue. I'm so new; I may not have understood your recommendation.

Comment: so ... what do you think each line in your loop is doing? you don't seem to be using the `$Folder` variable at all ... [*grin*]

Comment: Okay, thank you! Working on using $folder. Will report back. Appreciate your instruction.

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you so much @Lee_Daily. Posting solution above

Comment: you are very welcome! [*grin*] if you post the answer as an official Answer, i can vote for it ... please, do post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Lee_Daily, this is working:

```
$folders = get-ChildItem $home\Desktop\Project\ChapterOne -Directory
ForEach ($dir in $folders) {
    $FolderPath = $dir.FullName
    $outFile = Join-Path $FolderPath "AllTables.txt"
    $fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath\Table*.txt
        foreach ($file in $filelist)
        {
        Get-Content $file | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Encoding ascii -Append
        }
    }
```